# Translate CSS animation not working properly (jumping/lagging)

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm building a website with different divs sliding in and out of the screenview to get on top of the main div;
the ones coming from the top and the left are doing their job alright, sliding on click and going back out of the screenview on click as well.

But the bottom one and the right one are jumping or lagging depending on the browser. Could anyone help me and find out what I'm doing wrong?

(I'm searching for css-only solutions since I have no knowledge of Java or PHP, I'm quite new at coding)

```css
html{
background-color: #CEF1E8;}


body{margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
background-color: #CEF1E8;
overflow: hidden;}


.nav-top {
display: block;
position: fixed;
width: 100vw;
text-align: center;
z-index: 2; }

.nav-down {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100vw;
text-align: center;
z-index: 2; }

.nav-left{display: auto;
position: absolute;
z-index:2;
top:0;
left:0;
height: 100%;
text-align: center;
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
transform: translate(1.6vw);
margin: 0 auto;
z-index: 2; }

.nav-right{position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
top:0;
right: 0;
height: 100%;
text-align: center;
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
transform: rotate(180deg) translate(1.6vw);
transform-origin: center;
z-index: 2; }


.menu-top {text-decoration: none;
font-family: "Bodoni-36-Bold";
color: #FE632D;
font-size: 3vw;
cursor: pointer;
margin: 0.5vw;}

@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {.menu-top { font-size: 2.5vw;}}

.menu-contact {text-decoration: none;
font-family: "Bodoni-36-Bold";
color: #FE632D;
font-size: 3vw;
cursor: pointer;
margin: 0.5vw;}

@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {.menu-contact { font-size: 2.5vw;}}

.menu-about {text-decoration: none;
font-family: "Bodoni-36-Bold";
color: #FE632D;
font-size: 3vw;
cursor: pointer;
margin: 0.5vw;}

@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {.menu-about { font-size: 2.5vw;}}

.menu-work {text-decoration: none;
font-family: "Bodoni-36-Bold";
color: #FE632D;
font-size: 3vw;
cursor: pointer;
margin: 0.5vw;}

@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {.menu-work { font-size: 2.5vw;}}


.menu-home {text-decoration: none;
font-family: "Bodoni-36-Bold";
color: #CEF1E8;
font-size: 3vw;
cursor: pointer;
margin: 0.5vw;}

@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {.menu-home { font-size: 2.5vw;}}

.panel#home {
  z-index: 1;
  background: #CEF1E8;
    canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block; 
    }
}

.panel {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 500;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

.panel#slice {
  background-color: pink;
  transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.560, 1.000);
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%); 
}

.panel#slice:target {
  transform: translateY(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0); 
}

.panel#slice2 {
  background-color: #FFF7C8;
  transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.560, 1.000);
  transform-origin: 100% 100% 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
}

.panel#slice2:target {
  transform: translateX(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
}

.panel#slice3 {
  background-color: #FE632D;
  transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.560, 1.000);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.panel#slice3:target {
  transform: translateX(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0); 
}

.panel#slice4 {
  background-color: #005248;
  transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.560, 1.000);
  transform: translateY(100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100%); 
}

.panel#slice4:target {
  transform: translateY(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);  
}

/* and aditionaly some delays animation, don't know if it's relevant */

.panel-content {
  will-change: margin-top;
  transition: all 700ms; 
  transition-delay: 600ms;
  margin-top: -5%; 
}

.panel:target .panel-content {
  margin-top: 0; 
}

.panel-content2 {
  will-change: margin-top;
  transition: all 700ms; 
  transition-delay: 600ms;
  margin-right: -5%; 
}

.panel:target .panel-content2 {
  margin-right: 0; 
}

.panel-content3 {
  will-change: margin-top;
  transition: all 700ms; 
  transition-delay: 600ms;
  margin-left: -5%; 
}

.panel:target .panel-content3 {
  margin-left: 0; 
}

.panel-content4 {
  will-change: margin-top;
  transition: all 700ms; 
  transition-delay: 600ms;
  margin-bottom: -5%; 
}

.panel:target .panel-content4 {
  margin-bottom: 0; 
}
```

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="menuphone.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Alizée Laurent, graphic designer and illustrator, welcome to my website!">
    <meta name="author" content="Alizée Laurent">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
</head>
<body>
<header>
        
</header>
    
<main>
    
<div class="nav-top"> <a class="menu-top" href="#slice" data-hover="Slice">top</a> </div>
<div class="nav-left"><a class="menu-contact" href="#slice3" data-hover="Slice3">Contact</a></div>
<div class="nav-right"><a class="menu-about" href="#slice2" data-hover="Slice2">About me</a></div>  
<div class="panel" id="home">
    <h1 class="name-home">Alizée Laurent</h1>
</div>
<div class="nav-down"><a class="menu-work" href="#slice4" data-hover="Slice4">Work</a></div>



<div class="panel" id="slice">
    <div class="panel-content">
            <h3>holli</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-right"><a class="menu-home" href="#home" >Homepage</a></div>
</div>
    
<div class="panel" id="slice2">
    <div class="panel-content2">
            <h3>More about me</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-left"><a class="menu-home" href="#home" >Homepage</a></div>
</div>

    
<div class="panel" id="slice3">
    <div class="panel-content3">    
        <h3>contact</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-right"><a class="menu-home" href="#home" >Homepage</a></div>
</div>

    
<div class="panel" id="slice4">
    <div class="panel-content4">
        <h3>work</h3>
    </div>  
    <div class="nav-top"><a class="menu-home" href="#home" >Homepage</a></div>
</div>

   
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: unfortunatly I cant reproduce the error with the code given. There is no animations or buttons running even after merging.

Comment: How is it animating? I copied your code into codepen and nothing was animating.

Comment: I think the question asker means they want the scrolling to be smooth, which can be done by adding `scroll-behavior: smooth;` to the `html` tag in your css file.

Comment: @Ameer, I dont think so, there is a transition code within the CSS but there are to many vital parts of the code missing to reproduce the whole issue.

Comment: Sorry, I'll add the rest of the code, I tough it was enough to see the mistake!